# Text begin with A in pug

Tags: html, hyperlink, pug

I have a code like this in Pug. But Pug retranscribes this in Html with a balise  but I don't want . It's just my text who begin with A.

```
ul 
 li 
  A list of the relevant
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the content of your li in the same line

```
ul 
 li A list of the relevant
```

will render to

```
<ul>  <li>A list of the relevant</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You are my hero

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ul
    li.
        A list of the relevant
```

Or

```
ul
    li
        | A list of the relevant
```

Or

```
ul
    li A list of the relevant
```